# Error when opening Tor Browser

Tags: proxy, tor

When I type in "tor" in the terminal, I get this:

```
May 08 19:10:14.366 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips and Zlib 1.2.8.
May 08 19:10:14.366 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 08 19:10:14.366 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 08 19:10:14.371 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 08 19:10:14.371 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
May 08 19:10:14.371 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
May 08 19:10:14.371 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

How do I fix this and run tor? (I am on 16.04)

Thanks,

Comment: I am not a tor user myself , but according to the output it fails binding the port 9050 which is most likely caused as this port is already in use. Please ensure tor isnt already running. If it isnt check what is currently using the port and either change that port or tell tor to use another one

Answer (score 0):

```
May 08 19:10:14.371 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
```

This is letting us know that you already have a service running on the port that Tor is trying to use.  We can see what it is with:

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep 9050
```

If the process running on that port is indeed `tor`, that means that as it suspects, it's in fact already running.

Comment: your commands returns this: 

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9944/tor

Comment: As I suspected, that means that `tor` is already running.